# 'vi' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I give edit command in sqlplus, I'm receiving the below error:

[image]

I searched on the net and I think, I need to update the environment variable.
 
Current path value is:

> E:\app\sasinghc\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;D:\app\sasinghc\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID
>   Token
>   Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\

I updated this value to

> C:\Windows\System32

but it got even worse, I was unable to open sqlplus, so I rollback the changes.
Now, my sqlplus is working but still I'm able to open afiedt.buf file.

Can you please suggest on this?

Comment: It would be better to copy the text from your SQL\*Plus session and paste that in - as formatted text, not an image. Do you have vi (or vim) installed on your PC? The editor is set to Notepad by default, so you're overriding that somewhere. Which editor do you actually want to use?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take your advice. 
I want to use notepad.

Comment: We have a new command line interface, SQLcl, which has a built in line editor - at the command line. You can 'arrow around' your statement, w/o having to leave the program to edit it. you can read about it briefly here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/06/updated-sqlcl-nicer-inline-editing-and-column-completion/

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - Thanks, I'll learn about it, its completely new to me. Just want to say- your blogs are really helpful. They have helped me in various situation. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: no worries @AlbertEinstein - it's basically SQL*Plus with a few new tricks - and thanks for the feedback on the blog!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a Windows installation of Oracle uses Notepad as the SQL*Plus editor. You seem to have changed that to vi, possibly accidentally.

You can see the current setting with:

```
SQL> define _editor
```

which will presumably just show 'vi'. To change it back to Notepad you would do:

```
SQL> define _editor = "Notepad"
```

or use the full path. If you have vim installed you can give the full path to that as well, since it doesn't seem to be in your path variable.

You can read more [about `DEFINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm) and more specicially [the `EDITOR` value](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm#sthref1489) in the SQL*Plus documentation.

You may be picking this change up automatically via a login.sql or glogin.sql profile script - perhaps copied from a Linux/UNIX environment or a PC with Gnu tool installed, etc. If you find and edit that file you can make that change to your preferred editor automatic - whenever SQL*Plus runs it will invoke that login script and set things up for you. It appears it is also currently setting your SQL prompt, so you need to change the file, not replace it completely.

[Read more about SQL*Plus configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#i1132910) via profile scripts.

Answer (score 3):

`ED[IT]` command run external editor defined by `_EDITOR` variable. You can view all variable values with `DEF[INE]` command. I think you must reset `_EDITOR` value to some INSTALLED external editor, as Notepad or Wordpad. Use `DEF[INE] _EDITOR` command, for example: `def _editor = notepad`